# I'm getting error in matching password validation in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have tried all methods but finally I'm getting this error.

ERROR in C:/laragon/www/myapp/src/app/registration/registration.component.ts (30,9): Argument of type '{ validator: any; }' is not a
ssignable to parameter of type 'ValidatorFn'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'validator' does not exist in type 'ValidatorFn'.

Here is my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, Validator, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';
//import { emailValidator, matchingPasswords } from '../../app/validators/validators';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-registration',
    templateUrl: './registration.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./registration.component.css']
})
export class RegistrationComponent implements OnInit {
    private RegistrationForm: FormGroup;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.RegistrationForm = new FormGroup({
            firstname: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(3)
            ]),
            email: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
            ]),
            passwords: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.minLength(6)
            ]),
            confirmpwd: new FormControl(null, [
                Validators.required
            ]),
        }, { validator: matchingPasswords.bind('passwords', 'confirmpwd') });

        function matchingPasswords(passwordKey: string, confirmPasswordKey: string) {
            return (group: FormGroup): { [key: string]: any } => {
                let password = group.controls[passwordKey];
                let confirmPassword = group.controls[confirmPasswordKey];

                if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
                    return {
                        mismatchedPasswords: true
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43888447/6294072

Answer (score 2):

This could technically be a duplicate of this: **[Repeat password validation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43887201/repeat-password-validation-not-working)** (which I also linked earlier).

But, now I wanted to point out a "new finding" when trying your code. Wasn't able to reproduce the exact error you have in the Plunker, but I **did** manage to get an error. For some reason an error is thrown when using `new FormGroup()` when building form. I do **not** know why this is, and I'd be happy if someone can tell me why! :)

So at least in the plunker everything seems to be fine when using `FormBuilder` instead:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { } // inject formbuilder

ngOnInit() {
  this.RegistrationForm = this.fb.group({
    firstname: new FormControl(null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.minLength(3)
        ]),
        email: new FormControl(null, [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
        ]),
    passwords : new FormControl(null,[
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(6)
  ]),
  confirmpwd : new FormControl(null,[
    Validators.required
  ]),         
  },{validator: this.matchingPasswords}) // remember to use 'this'
}
```

And then the `matchingPasswords`-function, which is basically an exact copy of what was provided in (my) answer in the link mentioned in the beginning of this answer.

```ts
matchingPasswords = (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} =>{

  const newPassword = control.get('passwords');
  const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmpwd');
  // if no values, valid
  if (!newPassword || !confirmPassword) {
    return null;
  } 
  // if values match return null, else 'mismatchedPasswords:true'  
  return newPassword.value === confirmPassword.value ? null : { mismatchedPasswords: true };
}
```

Finally a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/xqKSLEqPTTfSsrJcl0EJ?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your matchingPasswords function isn't being recognized as a ValidatorFn and I think its because it has different arguments. The ValidatorFn expects you to pass in an AbstractControl instead.

Here is a link to [where the ValidatorFn interface is declared](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.0/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L163-L168) and the interface looks like:

```
export interface ValidatorFn { (c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null; }
```

Here is an example of how I write your validator:

```
matchingPasswords(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
  let password = c.get(['passwords']);
  let confirmPassword = c.get(['confirmpwd']);

  if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
    return { mismatchedPasswords: true };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Angular will pass the formGroup into matchingPasswords which will then access the passwords using the getter get().

You can then add it to your form group like this:

```
this.RegistrationForm = new FormGroup({
  firstname : new FormControl(null,[
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(3)
  ]),
  email : new FormControl(null,[
    Validators.required,
    Validators.pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/)
  ]),
  passwords : new FormControl(null,[
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(6)
  ]),
  confirmpwd : new FormControl(null,[
    Validators.required
  ]), 
}, {validator: matchingPasswords} );
```

By the way I like to put all my validators in a Validator Class that can be imported into my services. It might help you to do it similarly.

```
export class FormValidator {

  static nonEmpty(control: any) {
    if (!control.value || control.value.length === 0) {
      return { 'noElements': true };
    }
    return null;
  }


  matchingPasswords(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    let password = c.get(['passwords']);
    let confirmPassword = c.get(['confirmpwd']);

    if (password.value !== confirmPassword.value) {
      return { mismatchedPasswords: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

And then you can use it in your forms like this:

```
{ validator: FormValidator.matchingPasswords }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: Have you tried passing in the matchingPasswords function directly like this:
`this.RegistrationForm = new FormGroup({
...
}, matchingPasswords)`